# vagrant: Post task to remove vagrant user

Tags: vagrant, provisioning

I am provisioning a `vagrant` machine using `ansible`;

The question is whether it is possible to run some kind of post-processing (either in `ansible` or in any other form of `vagrant` provisioning) so as to remove the `vagrant` user at the end of the day (or at least disable it)?

Will this break the `vagrant` process/provisioning itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `Vagrantfile` demonstrates it's possible:

```
$script = <<-SCRIPT
useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 password) user
usermod --expiredate 1 vagrant
sed -i "s/^PasswordAuthentication no$/PasswordAuthentication yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
service sshd restart
SCRIPT

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/bionic64'
  config.vm.provision 'shell', inline: $script
end
```